# Cloud Jira Webook Not Firing on Workflow Update Events

Tags: cloud, jira, webhooks

#### Question

Is there anything special with jira epics that would preclude them from firing an issue updated event for a webhook when they're tranistioned? Any tricks to get issue_updated events to fire for epic transitions?

#### Background

We sync the cloud jira to an external system. It works pretty well. All issue type except epics are synced when transitioned, but for whatever reasons epics don't seem to fire the update event when transitioned. Epic is created in JIRA, but never synced. I've confirmed the webhook endpoint never receives anything in this case. However, if you edit the epic, that *does* trigger the issue_updated event and it syncs.

Here's my set up (can't get images to work inline, apologies)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xucvzz8eb4rxfu/Screenshot%202017-06-21%2022.52.34.png?dl=0

#### Manual Workaround

The issue doesn't seem to impact the update event. If I make any trivial update the webhook fires, and the epic gets synced.

#### The Ask

Any tricks to getting the issue_created event to fire for sprints for my webhook? I'm open to weird options, just would prefer not to deal with support all things being equal.